# Create Mono Installer Package (OSX)

Tags: c#, macos, mono, installation, dmg

I have a C# Winforms application which I developed in Mono on OSX.

I would like to create an installer package which will install my application on any OSX computer.

How do I create an installer package ?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

This [blog entry](https://mjhutchinson.com/journal/2010/01/24/creating_mac_app_bundle_for_gtk_app) explains how to package a GTK# app. If you're not using Gtk, you can still possibly reuse many of the know-how of that post.